# Rails form_for and bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

How can I insert a glyphicon of twitter bootstrap that it would appear in the right hand side of input?

```
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email', autofocus: true %>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email', autofocus: true %>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```